# How to get the history back href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the search query or the full URL of the google page that entered my site.

My problem is not solved by doing document.referrer() because this method only gives the origin URL and not the full URL

Example

```
history.back().href
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no way to get it directly from the history object.
perhaps you should implement next to the original history object the own storage of history to be able to get the information about prev route

Comment: Is there another way to do this?

Comment: @reza history.pushState({prevUrl:'some_url_from_where'},...)